# How to cancel js toggle event by condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button, that shows a modal window:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="modal.html" id="btn_port" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portModal">Toggle!</button>
```

and a click event for this button:

```
$('#btn_port').click(function(event) {
     if(not_show_modal) {
        *** not_show_modal_action ***
     }
 }
```

How to prevent modal window appearence by condition in button click event?

and after all here is a decision:

```
    $('#btn_port').click(function(event) // нажатие на кнопку "Порт" для открытия модального окна
 {

    if($("#device_select").val()!=null)
    {

       $('#portModal').attr("data-remote", "portmodal.html/"+$("#device_select").val());           
       $('#portModal').modal('show');
    }

 });
```

Comment: what's the condition ?

Comment: condition is a state of a variable, for example, that says to show modal or not to do.

Comment: ok so where is this variable ?

Comment: if($("#device_select").val()!=null)

Comment: Remove the modal related data attributes and open modal yourself based on conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop the call like below,

```
$('#btn_port').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = 'bla';
    //var val = null;
    if(val != null){
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p9qhgfz9/2/)***

**Note:**
You can use your condition instead of `val`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a new example, when the `value` of the `select` element has a value, it will allow the toggle to function - otherwise it will not function.

*`Select an option` has a value of `""` which will be interpreted as `false`*

```js
$('[data-toggle]').on('click', function(){
  var active =  $('[data-option]').val()
  if(active) {
    var target = $(this).attr('data-toggle')
    $('[data-item="'+target+'"]').toggle();
  }
})
```

```css
* { text-align: center }
[data-item="menu"] {
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-option>
  <option value="">Select An Option</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="a">B</option>
</select>


<span data-toggle="menu">Toggle</span>

<div data-item="menu" style="display:none">
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: talk is about bootstrap modal window. I forgot its code:<div class="modal" id="portModal">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-lg">
    </div>
  </div></div>

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what that is supposed to mean - try to rephrase it?

Comment: I need to show bootstrap modal window by condition based on value of select input. User clicks a button: If there is no any value in select input- not to show modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here- http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1188/

```
  $('button').on('click',function(){
      if($('select').val().length>0){
      $('#myModal1').modal('show');
     }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, guys, I removed all related data attributes and open window by click.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap models can be show or hide like this

```
$('#basicModal').modal('hide'); // To hide
$('#basicModal').modal('show'); // To show
```

```js
$('#model_opener').click(function(){
  if($('#check').prop('checked')){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  Open or not?:  <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="model_opener" >Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```